# How are the Spring @Transactional and the Hibernate @LockMode annotations related

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, locking

I wish to know the relation between transactions and locks.

To be more specific, how is Spring's `@Transactional` related to Hibernate's LockMode. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html.
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

If I dont specify any lock while creating Session Object, and use `@Transactional` with `readOnly` as `false`, am I using Pessimistic Concurrenct Control.

It would be a great help, if anyone can tell me the relation between (Optimistic/Pessimistic) Concurrency Control and Transactions.

Thank you,
Vivek

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no **direct** relationship between `@Transactional` and `@LockMode` annotations.

[`@Transactional`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) is used to mark the explicit boundaries of a RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA transaction. The reason why you need it is that every database statement executes in a transactional context, and, if you don't set the transaction boundaries, you'll get one transaction per statement or auto-commit.

On the other hand, `@LockModeType` is for setting explicit locking options. If you don't set it, the implicit locking mechanisms will be used:

- Implicit locks are acquired on every modified row on both 2PL and MVCC database engines. Shared locks are acquired on read records on 2PL engines if you use Repeatable Read on Serializable.
- If you defined a [`@Version`](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-version-property-jpa-hibernate/) property, the **implicit** optimistic locking mechanism will be used.

So, `@LockModeType` is for setting locking options **explicitly**, and you can have the following options:

- [`LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/)
- [`LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`](https://vladmihalcea.com//hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/)

The `PESSIMISTIC` lock modes will always acquire a database lock on the table row that is associated with the locked entity.

There are also explicit optimistic lock strategies:

- [`LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic-lock-mode-work/)
- [`LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/)
- [`LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-pessimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/)

The `OPTIMISTIC` lock modes are meant to give you a way of bumping up an entity version even if the entity hasn't changed in the currently running Persistence Context. This is a very useful mechanism when you need to coordinate multiple child entities using their parent entity version.

There are lots of examples in the links that I provided in this answer, so take your time, read them all, and you'll understand all these concepts in greater detail.

Comment: do I understand it correctly - only by `@Version` annotation an implicit lock is set? Otherwise it must be used explicitly?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. The implicit lock is associated with any row change whether optimistic locking is used to not.

Comment: You're listing possibilities of implicit locks and the first dot starts with "Explicit locks are acquired on every modified row...". You mean "Implicit locks", right? Or rather exclusive?

Comment: Good catch. I restructured the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Spring's `@Transactional` and Hibernate's `LockMode` class are different.

**Spring Transaction Management**

`@Transactional` is a Spring annotation for declarative transaction management, i.e. defining what SQL statements are executed together inside of a database transaction.  Using the `readOnly` attribute allows Spring to throw an exception if you attempt to insert rows inside of a read-only transaction, for example.

With respect to locking, however, you'll most likely be using a read/write (`readOnly = false`) transaction, because you'll be attempting to modify data.

**Pessimistic Locking**

Hibernate's `LockMode` is used for pessimistic locking, e.g. `LockMode.UPGRADE` actually executes a `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` statement, and locks the row in the database corresponding to the entity.

> Pessimistic locking assumes that concurrent transactions will conflict
>   with each other, and requires resources to be locked after they are
>   read and only unlocked after the application has finished using the
>   data.

**Optimistic Locking**

Optimistic concurrency control in Hibernate typically uses a version or timestamp column in the database.  The idea here is that if multiple transactions attempt to modify a row concurrently, all but the first committed transaction will detect that the version number has changed and perform a rollback.

> Optimistic locking assumes that multiple transactions can complete
>   without affecting each other, and that therefore transactions can
>   proceed without locking the data resources that they affect. Before
>   committing, each transaction verifies that no other transaction has
>   modified its data. If the check reveals conflicting modifications, the
>   committing transaction rolls back.

Quotes above are from: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Comment: Thank you @CK1. I already know what you mentioned. The thing which I dont know is which is used when. I know Spring `@Transactional` is used for transaction management, and mostly it is annotated on service method. By the use of `@Transactional`, I can manage concurrent transactions, then why is `LockMode` or `@Version` needed. Could you please explain via use-cases or examples for each.

Comment: Use pessimistic locking when collisions happen frequently.

Use optimistic locking when collisions aren't expected to happen.

Locking is needed when two or more database transactions are modifying the same row concurrently.