# Making a method transactional in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I use a hibernate as JPA provider

```
@RestController
public class RestController {
    private final TestService testService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/file/{entityId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public void test(@PathVariable @NotNull UUID entityId) {
        testService.delete(entityId);
    }
}

class TestService {
    @AutoWired
    EntityRepository repo; // <- Crud repository from Spring Data

    public void delete(UUID id2){
        //if row not exists with id == id2 
            throw NoFoundException
        // else
            //remove from database using repo.
    }
}
```

And how to resolve the following case:

1. "if row not exists with id == id2 " evaluated to false, because object exists in fact.
2. Other thread deleted that row.
3. "remove from database using repo" <- error, there is no such row because it was removed by other thread in the step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Transactional` on your Service methods to ensure your database operations run in a transaction. By default, you can roll back the transaction if you throw a unchecked exception inside the annotated method. You can also specify on which exceptions to rollback using `@Transactional`'s rollbackFor Parameter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you've got a delete method that is basically doing exactly the same as the SimpleJpaRepository delete method, so for starters I'd change your code to

```
repo.delete(entityId)
```

and get rid of test service.

If you are worried about getting a EmptyResultDataAccessException when there is no data to delete, either catch the exception and ignore it or use pessimistic locking on whatever else is doing deletes, as explained 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980677/how-are-the-spring-transactional-and-the-hibernate-lockmode-annotations-relate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation @Transaction for your service method delete(UUID id2).Default propagation of @Transaction is Propagation.REQUIRED which means that if you get an existing transaction it continues that and if you do not have existing transaction it will create one for you.